# Refresh the UITableView with a complete refresh of the data

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a view which shows a list of entries in a UITableView. The data for the list is an NSArray. When the user is on this view, there is an asynchronous call to a webservice to retrieve the latest entries. When I have downloaded the latest entries, I update the NSArray and then I send off a notification to the notification center. The UITableView is listening to this event and will try to reload the table.
But with this approach I get an error which is on the lines of "The object was mutated during reading".

After going through similar questions here on SO, I see the suggested approach is to remove objects and add objects at individual indexes and ask the table view to reload the data.

Is there a way to replace the array completely and ask the table view to reload the data ?

Answer (score 0):

UITableView's reloadData method should do the trick.

From Apple's documentation:

> Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the
>   table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and
>   so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that
>   are visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of
>   the reload. The table view's delegate or data source calls this
>   method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data. It
>   should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows,
>   especially within an animation block implemented with calls to
>   beginUpdates and endUpdates

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData

Answer (score 0):

if you have `Updated NSArray Object`

Then you can use directly following method of `UITableView`

```
[tableView reloadData]
```